# Sub-set of Rows and Columns

Tags: linear-algebra

Given, K and T are sub-sets of Vector space V.

Denote K as row sub-sets, and T column subsets of matrix A (mxn).

Denote $K_1$ as row sub-sets, and $T_1$ column subsets of row equivalent matrix A (mxn).

**I need to show that:**

1. $Sp(K) = Sp(K_1)$
2. $Sp(T) \ne Sp(T_1)$

Well, i's pretty logical that $Sp(K) = Sp(K_1)$ is true because after using Elementary row operations we get a matrix which is equialent to the original matrix, but why their Columns won't necessary be equal? can I have an example of two matrices which will make $Sp(T) \ne Sp(T_1)$ true? and if possible and algebric explanation why $Sp(K) = Sp(K_1)$ is true, thx.

Comment: There's probably some assumption missing. Imagine $A$ to be the identity or any other square nonsingular matrix. Whatever equivalent row operation you do on such an $A$, nothing changes with the row and column spans.

Comment: Can you give me a matrix that will make $Sp(T) \ne Sp(T_1)$ true?

Comment: $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\ 1&1\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to show, but I still don't get why their columns are not equiavalent? after I use row operation I get that those 2 matrices are equal which means their columns are also equal.

Comment: Say, $\tilde{A}$ is the matrix made from $A$ by an equivalent row operation represented, say, by a nonsingular matrix $E$, that is, $\tilde{A}=EA$. If $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are columns of $A$, then generally they span different subspace than columns of $\tilde{A}$: $Ea_1,\ldots,Ea_n$.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I can't still see why the columns aren't equal because [1,1] and [1,1] will become [1,0] and [1,0].

Comment: Understood now. Thanks Pavel.